# How modifier this code to let checkbox values store into sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

im beginner on android app developer... spend almost two day on modifier and search solution for this kind of checkbox value store into sharedpreference...but failed. gt any other method to rewrite this coding so checkbox value can be store in sharedpreference. Hope expert can hlp...thk     `

```
CheckBox blockAll_cb;
BroadcastReceiver CallBlocker;
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
ITelephony telephonyService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);

    initviews();
    blockAll_cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            CallBlocker =new BroadcastReceiver()
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    Class c = null;
                    try {
                        c = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Method m = null;
                    try {
                        m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(telephonyManager);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    telephonyManager.listen(callBlockListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                }
                PhoneStateListener callBlockListener = new PhoneStateListener()
                {
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
                    {
                        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
                        {
                            if(blockAll_cb.isChecked())
                            {
                                try {
                                    telephonyService.endCall();
                                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            };//BroadcastReceiver
            IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
            registerReceiver(CallBlocker, filter);
        }
    });

}
public void initviews()
{
    blockAll_cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbBlockAll);
    //blockcontacts_cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbBlockContacts);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if (CallBlocker != null)
    {
        unregisterReceiver(CallBlocker);
        CallBlocker = null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
  public boolean getFromSP(String key){
        SharedPreferences preferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences("Contacts", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        }
  private void saveInSp(String key,boolean value){
        SharedPreferences preferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences("Contacts", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
        }
```

in your view  write as shown below

```
 holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
                { 
                    saveInSp("check"+position,true);
                    Log.i("pos", ""+position);   

                }       
                else
                {
                    saveInSp("check"+position,false);
                }
```

to retrieve the checked state of checkbox when loading the listview, use this in your required method -

```
 holder.checkBox.setChecked(getFromSP("check"+position));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SharedPreferences preferences =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    // value to store
     editor.putBoolean(Value, key); 
    editor.commit();
```

Use it where you want to store the values give key to retrieve it later